# Issue with the value of the flot line stacked chart?

Tags: jquery, flot, linechart

I have a problem regarding Flot Stacked Line chart,
I need a line chart in stacking order and i have reproduced that and the graphs are drawn one above the other but when i hover the points the graph at the bottom displays correct values but the graph above that(when hovered on the points) will add the difference and display
Eg if the first graph data is 5 and 2nd graph data is 10
when hovered on first graph 'Data=5'
when hovered on 2nd graph 'Data=15'
how do i resolve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from the [flot interacting example](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/examples/interacting/index.html) replace

```
y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);
```

with

```
y = (item.datapoint[1] - item.datapoint[2]).toFixed(2);
```

to get only the difference from the current line to the underlying line.